# GitHub Pages не загружает данные

Tags: github, github-pages

Проект написан на React, сборку для gh-pages делал через команду "gh-pages -d public".

В итоге GitHub не читает данные, кроме bundle.js, index.css и index.html.

[Демо](https://konstantinlypskyi.github.io/Web-Market/#/)

[Репозиторий](https://github.com/KonstantinLypskyi/Web-Market)

Comment: Чтобы работал github-pages вам нужен в корне index.html к которому прикручен css и js. Реакт он не будет собирать самостоятельно. Можно в реакте делать сборку в статичные файлы и их загружать.

Comment: @Ljil, там есть ветка gh-pages, где все это прикручено

Comment: Не загружаются любые картинки, json файлы, которые находятся локально в папках, в консоле выдает 404 ошибку. По пути  https://konstantinlypskyi.github.io/Web-Market/#/images тоже не грузит.

Comment: Всё должно быть в мастере

Comment: https://github.com/Ljil/Ljil.github.io
Вот мой древний заброшенный проект, вот как файлы все хранятся. В мастере и никаких излишеств.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему перекинув данные на чужой хостинг. Если кто-то знает другой способ, пишите.

UPD: проблема была до смешного проста. Нужно было добавить точку в начало пути.